# Display Timer in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, timer

Hi Im trying to display a labelField that shows a timer...
The timer should start when a button is clicked, so the following code is inside a fieldChanged autogenerated method because I implement FieldChangeListener...
This is the code:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
Date startTime = new Date();
LabelField courseTime = new LabelField()
t.schedule(new TimerTask(){

public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Date now = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
courseTime.setText(date.formatLocal(now.getTime() - startTime.getTime()));
}}, 0, 10);
```

I have two problems with this code:
When I click on the button I have a IllegalStateException.. Don't know where it comes from
but I have commented this section and it comes from here..
Then, after I accept the exception, the timer starts, but the format is 19:00:00, not 00:00:00 like I wished...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to explain little bit more about the time format you are trying to achieve. I have answered only the part of `updating LabelField text without getting exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Any operation involving the device's user interface must be done with the lock, [UiApplication.getEventLock()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#getEventLock%28%29) held.

Try following code for updating `LabelField` text.

```java
synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
    courseTime.setText("some text");
}
```

Comment: yep that did the trick... I just wanna show the hours, minutes and seconds since the user clicked the button... For that, I put that pattern (HH:mm:ss) to the simpleDateFormat... When I show the timer, it does not initialize in 00:00:00 and starts counting, but it starts with 19:00:00... I think the error might be in the pattern but not sure..

Comment: I have to say something about your question. Don't get me wrong. I think surely you didn't post the actual code you are using on your project, because your posted code have compilation error. If it's not possible to post actual code due to some restriction then you can create a test project, and post the code that represent the problem, and of course what you have done so far. On your code, you didn't paste anything about initialization of the variable `startTime`. It is important to answer the question. And everybody doesn't have the mind reading skill, :). So, please update your question.